# What does ("<<") mean in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, bitwise-xor

I don't understand how `a<<b` works.

And what does it actually mean  for `a+= arr[i][j] ==0 && tfunc(i,j);` ?

Does it mean:

```
if (arr[i][j]==0 && tfunc(i,j) == true)
    a += 1;
```

Part of the code will be as follow:

```
int *eFunc(int* a) const{
   for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
      for(int j=0; j<8; ++j){
         *a = b <<3^j; 
          a+= arr[i][j] ==0 && tfunc(i,j); 
      }
   }
   return a;
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means that there are programmers out there with a terrible idea of what good code is. You may want to read about operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @stefan this might be hand-optimized code to remove branches. But it really should be heavily commented...

Comment: Which particular bits don't you understand? The syntax? The operator precedence? The logic it actually implements?

Comment: @stefan But hey, as long as it looks cool you're a good programmer.

Comment: `<<` is the shift or stream operator - in this case, bit shifting

Comment: Exactly. So, why isn't the question _what does `<<` mean_?

Comment: which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*a = b <<3^j;
```

Thanks to @Holt for pointing out that `<<` has a higher priority than `^`. Let's do it step by step:

```
(b << 3) ^ j
b << 3     // Bitshifting operator. Shift b to the left by 3`
           // So for b = 0b0001  you get 0b1000 = 8
       ^ j // XOR with j for example
           // 0b1000 ^ 0b0010 = 0b1010 = 10
```

and at the end you assign that value to the place where `a` points to.

```
a+= arr[i][j] ==0 && tfunc(i,j); 
    arr[i][j] ==0                // if the element [i][j] from arr == 0 return true
                     tfunc(i,j)  // return of tfunc
                  &&             // if both statements are !=0, results 
                                 // in true, else in false
a+=                              // a = a + true or false is equal to
                                 // a = a + 1    or 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to learn more and have better understanding on this part. Are there any keywords for this kind of coding?

Comment: First part is bitwise operations. Second part is just bad coding style ;) You can also search for logic operators.

Comment: First part of this answer is wrong - `b << 3 ^ j` is `(b << 3) ^ j` not `b << (3 ^ j)`. `<<` has priority over `^`.

Comment: @izlin Thanks again. But for the second part, why it returns true whatever tfunc returns if element[i][j] from arr ==0?  `&&` is not meaning that if `a && b` both true, it will return true, else false?

Comment: @kandleIce I was unclear in my explanation. If `arr[i][j] == 0` and the return value of tfunc `!= 0` this will result in true. You are right, with whatever i meant that i have no idea what the return value of tfunc is

Comment: @izlin Thanks for detail explanation.